# Three.js texture alignment/scaling with proctree.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render a model created by SnappyTree/Proctree ( http://www.snappytree.com/ ).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430319/importing-snappytree-proctree-model), that showed how to render the trunk geometry using Three.js instead of [proctree.js](https://github.com/supereggbert/proctree.js)'s author's GLGE project. I've got that working now but the texture on the twigs (branches) doesn't align properly. Any ideas how to make the texture fit on?

http://jsfiddle.net/nhspjkb4/

This is how the material is created:

```
  // Load texture from data URI in js fiddle
  var twigTexture = getTexture('branch');

  // Scaling the texture seems to help
  twigTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  twigTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  twigTexture.repeat.set( 1/2.5, 1/2.5 );

  // immediately use the texture for material creation
  var twigMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: twigTexture,
        transparent: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
```

This is how it renders:

[image: tree rendered with branch textures incorrect]

With a solid color, it's clear that the branch vertices/faces are in the correct places:

[image]

Each branch should look like the texture image:

[image: branch texture image]

Comment: A reasonable guess is your `faceVertexUvs` are not correct for the branches. I would expect the branch uv coords to be 0 or 1, only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice tree.

To fix the texturing, first update the proctree.js to three.js conversion code to use the `tree.uvsTwig` array, instead of `tree.UV`, for the twigs:

```js
tree[isTwigs ? 'facesTwig' : 'faces'].forEach(function(f) {
    var uv = isTwigs ? tree.uvsTwig : tree.UV;
    output.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(f[0], f[1], f[2]));
    output.faceVertexUvs[0].push(f.map(function(v) {
        return new THREE.Vector2(uv[v][0], uv[v][1]);
    }));
});
```

Then, enable alpha testing for the material:

```js
var twigMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: twigTexture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    alphaTest: 0.5
});
```

Finally, remove the texture scaling (`twigTexture.repeat.set(...)`).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhspjkb4/6/.